# Ruby: unterminated regexp meets end of file

Tags: ruby

I just installed Ruby... I'm usually more of a C# guy; but I wanted to learn it for web-design purposes. It WAS working; and then suddenly (after changing nothing) it stopped working - providing the error instead.

Below is the error report from my (Windows) CMD line. Below that is the code I'm trying to run (it may have Syntax errors. I'm still pretty new to Ruby).

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Alex>cd C:/Users/Alex/Desktop

C:\Users\Alex\Desktop>ruby r.rb
r.rb:1: unterminated regexp meets end of file

C:\Users\Alex\Desktop>
```

Code I am trying to run:

```
numX = 0 // where it begins

for numX in 0..1000 do 
    if numX % 3 == 0 || numX % 5 == 0
        puts "Number: #numX"
    end 
end
```

Comment: `//` is afaik not "start of comment" in ruby, `#` is.

Comment: That did it! Nasty habit from C#! Haha. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're mixing up Ruby comments with those from C#! Comments in Ruby are delimited by the hash mark: `#`

Forward slashes are used to delimit regular expressions in Ruby, which is why you're getting that error from the parser:

```
/hello/.match('hello') # => #<MatchData "hello"> 
/hell/.match('hello') # => #<MatchData "hell"> 
//.match('hello') # => #<MatchData "">
// == Regexp.new('') # => true
```

The parser thinks that the regular expression is "unterminated" because its interpreting the first `/` as a division operator (since it comes after a number literal) and the second `/` as the start of a regular expression. If you put a `/` at the end of the file you'll actually notice that Ruby will attempt to divide `0` by the regular expression, and you'll reasonably get the following error: `TypeError: Regexp can't be coerced into Fixnum`.

Comment: The interpreter thinks the first `/` marks division since it comes after a number literal.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks.